# Lightbox with transition

Tags: css, transition, lightbox

I wanted to do a smooth transition of a fullscreen lightbox, my actual code is

```
<a href="#_" class="lightbox" id="img1">
<img src="images/photo.jpg">
</a>
```

And my style:

```
.lightbox {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
.lightbox img {
    max-width: 90%;
    max-height: 80%;
    margin-top: 2%;
}
.lightbox:target {
    outline: none;
    display: block;
    transition:all 1s;
}
```

It's really simple, but transition:all seems to don't work with display block/none... Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`display block/none` does not allow any transition to run.

You must use `visibility` and `opacity`(for cross browser support).

So your code would look like this:

```
.lightbox {
    display: block;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    transition:all 1s;
}
.lightbox img {
    max-width: 90%;
    max-height: 80%;
    margin-top: 2%;
}
.lightbox:target {
    outline: none;
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly, `transition` doesn't work with `display`. It's not time to give up hope, however! There's `opacity`! Use `opacity: 0` and `opacity: 1` in combination with `display: none` and `display: block`. Also, your `transition` is on the *`.lightbox:target`*, not the *`.lightbox`*. When it's on `.lightbox:target`, it's too late to start the transition.

Corrected CSS:

```
.lightbox {
    display: none;
    opacity: 1;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    transition: opacity 1s;
}
.lightbox img {
    max-width: 90%;
    max-height: 80%;
    margin-top: 2%;
}
.lightbox:target {
    outline: none;
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Same answer but 2 minutes late :)

Answer (score 1):

you can't transition `display` since it has no interim values, it is either displayed or hidden (of course there are many different ways of display)
It can't be 25% displayed

in order to create fade in transition with css only, you'll need to use the `opacity` attribute

```js
function toggle(){
  var element = document.getElementById("element");
  if(element.className==""){
    element.className = "out";
  } else {
    element.className = "";
  }
}
```

```css
#element{
  transition: all 1s;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  opacity: 1; 
}

#element.out{
  opacity:0
}

button{z-index: 2; position: relative}
```

```html
<div id="element">Element</div>

<br />
<button onclick="toggle()">click to fade in/out</button>
```